# How to get the log in with Facebook button that this website uses?

Tags: css, facebook

I'm adding a Facebook authentication system to my app, and the log in button that Facebook provides in their developers section isn't very please to look at.

**What I'm wondering:**

How does a website, such as Stack Overflow, get the log in with facebook button that they have. If you logout of this site, and then click the sign up or log in path, you'll see the button I'm talking about (it's right next to the red Google + button). Are they making it themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but there are premade social buttons to make your life easier, see here for bootstrap:

http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/

It's pretty easy to customize it; just edit their respective css files.

You could also make it on your own using pure CSS.

**Usage:**

Add the CDN to your header:

`<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/4.9.1/bootstrap-social.min.css" />`

Then place the button somewhere, and point it somewhere onClick():

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-social btn-facebook" onclick="location.href='SOME PATH'">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>Sign In With Facebook
</button>
```